# Detect xhr progress of php form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, httprequest, progress-bar

I have a form with action php on submit

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

this form on submit will load the page on executing the request;

What i want is with javascript, to detect the progress of the request to show user that his submit form is at N %; cause if i have a big treatment in my php, the user will not know where is the progress of his form; if using ajax we can catch the progress of request but with the case of only php form, i have no idea on how to catch the progress

Comment: That probably won't work at all, because when you do a normal form submission, the browser will prepare to "unload" the current document, preparing to display a new one. And that usually means cancelling all running scripts at some point.

Comment: The only way to implement anything like this in a web environment is with ajax, but mostly what you can achieve with that relates to file uploads. You can do more, but you'd likely need a much more complicated de-coupled setup where a background job actually does the hard work, and logs its progress, and then you have a web app with a websocket or SSE connection to the browser, which regularly reads/receives messages about the progress from the background job, and sends it in a real-time to the page to provide the user an update.